# Handling Empty Rows of Excel in Apex

Tags: apex, excel

I have a excel file in which 10 rows of data is written manually and later deleted 9 rows of data by selecting and pressing 'Delete(Keyboard button)'. While i read the file in apex its showing 10 rows of data in which 9 rows are getting as:

```
1st row data,
,,,,,,
,,,,,,
```

... so on

As a result, my code is throwing exceptions.  Is there a way to restrict it?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this. Remove all comma and check for size and if `length == 0` then ignore the line.

```
for(String line: lines) {
       if (line.replaceAll(',','').trim().length() == 0) break;
```